# Force DecimalField to convert a string into decimal - Django

Tags: python, django

I have this serializer:

```
class Ticker24hSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
        change = serializers.DecimalField(max_digits=19, decimal_places=4)
        change_percent = serializers.FloatField()
        current = serializers.DecimalField(max_digits=19, decimal_places=4)
        high = serializers.DecimalField(max_digits=19, decimal_places=4)
        low = serializers.DecimalField(max_digits=19, decimal_places=4)
    
        def update(self, instance, validated_data):
            pass
    
        def create(self, validated_data):
            pass
```

A dictionary contains decimal values like this:

```
dict = {
    "change": "2128.5000",
    "change_percent": "5.632",
    "current": "39517.3141",
    "high": "40900.0000",
    "low": "37350.0000"
}
```

However, these values are stored as strings in the dictionary.

When I serialize the dict:

```
result = serializer(dict).data
print(result)
```

I get this:

```
{
    "change": "2128.5000",
    "change_percent": 5.632,
    "current": "39517.3141",
    "high": "40900.0000",
    "low": "37350.0000"
}
```

DecimalFields are accepting strings, how can I make my serializer store decimals?

Comment: This is on purpose, since a decimal can have an arbitrary number of digits. By converting it to a float number, rounding errors can occur, so the only way to transfer a decimal without such errors is through a string.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem is right. Strings should be fine unless you want to work with `Decimal` objects: https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html

Comment: I have to do some calculations with these values, would I be able to do it with strings?

Comment: Check the `coerce_to_string` at documentation page: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#decimalfield